# VB.NET Import from assembly failed

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, import, reference

I added some code to an ASP.NET file within my Web project, and I got an error that I needed to add a reference. I added the needed reference in the VS menu `Website -> Add Reference...`.

Now I get an error:

```
BC31091 Import of type 'ITransactionalMapper' from assembly or module 'MyAssembly.Core.dll' failed. Web(7)  C:\Projects\project\src\PublicWeb\Web\MyFile.aspx.vb
```

I viewed the list of references for the Web project, and the reference I added is not in the list. I tried to add it again, and it says:

`The Web site is already referencing the assembly 'MyAssembly.Core.dll'`

So I decided I wanted to remove it and try adding it again. I cannot find a way to remove it, if it is even added somewhere. I looked in the Web.config file, and I do not see it in the list of assemblies.

I'm not really sure what the problem is or why I'm having it. The code that I added is using another referenced assembly, and *that* assembly may also be referencing the assembly I tried to add. The `ITransactionalMapper` is, to my knowledge, not even located within `MyAssembly.Core.dll`, it's located within `MyAssembly.Database.dll`.

I'm using VS 2015. The project is targeting .NET 4.5

---

**Note:** If I open the project in VS 2012 (the project is really a VS 2012 project), I instead get the error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Put' accepts this number of arguments.
```

But it should accept that number. It's the `Put` that has an `ITransactionalMapper` parameter that it can't find (the first one in the image below).

[image]

---

**Update: Two necessary references show up in VS 2015, but not when I view the Web project's references in VS 2012. Any idea why that would happen?**

---

I noticed a bunch of build warnings saying that `MyAssembly.Core.dll` has conflicting references.

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.
```

It also mentions the versions. But I still don't see those references anywhere.

Comment: VS2012 and VS2015 use different versions of msbuild so generate different errors. If ITransactionalMapper depends on something that is in MyAssembly.Core then it'll need the reference. The references are stored in the project file .vbproj, not the web.config. If you wish to delete or look from duplicates then do so in there. If you click Show All Files in Solution Explorer the references in your project will be listed.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi The references for non-Web projects are always visible. There is no "Show All Files" button when in the Web project because there are no hidden files. The references for Web are not shown in the solution explorer.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi The mapper class is in `MyAssembly.Core.dll` and the class calling `Put` is in `MyAssembly.Some.Other.Core.dll`. Could that be causing it?

Comment: @FloatingKiwi Also, `Web` projects do not have `vbproj` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referencing a version of `MyAssembly.Some.Other.Core.dll` that was built for a different version of `MyAssembly.Core.dll`. I tried another version, and it works.